# Get value from multi object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simply object:

```
var page = [
    {
        title: 'aaa',
        text:  '111'
    },     
    {
        title: 'bbb',
        text:  '222'
    },     
    {
        title: 'ccc',
        text:  '333'
    },     
    {
        title: 'ddd',
        text:  '444'
    }, 
];
```

Data are examples.

And i have string:

```
var to_get = '222, 444';
```

There are texts separated by commas. How can i get Title for this text?

For this example i would receive:

```
var to_return = 'bbb, ddd';
```

Separated by commas.

I try use $.each and $.inArray but i dont know how to combine this for multi array.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LnNb/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/YrZNq/9))

```
console.log('222, 444, bogus'.split(', ').reduce(function (p, c) {
    page.forEach(function (o) {
        if (o.text === c) p.push(o.title);
    });
    return p;
}, []).join(", "));
```

Comment: Nice answer...love the chain.

Comment: thanks, this working ok, but if i enter not exist text this return error. http://jsfiddle.net/YrZNq/1/ is possible to eliminate this error?